# Separate one column to three (via PS)

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

In CSV file I have data without headers in one column looking like:

```
data1;data2;data3

data1;data2;data3

data1;data2;data3
```

I don't know how to put this via PowerShell in 3 columns in CVS or XLSX.
Tried a few scripts but always same result - empty file or nothing changes.

My Code:

```
#Define locations and delimiter
$csv = "C:\TEMP\Loginy_Nieaktywne_temp.csv" #Location of the source file
$xlsx = "C:\TEMP\TEST.xlsx" #Desired location of output
$delimiter = ";" #Specify the delimiter used in the file

# Create a new Excel workbook with one empty sheet
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)

# Build the QueryTables.Add command and reformat the data
$TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $csv)
$Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
$query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)
$query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $delimiter
$query.TextFileParseType  = 1
$query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,1 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
$query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1

# Execute & delete the import query
$query.Refresh()
$query.Delete()

# Save & close the Workbook as XLSX.
$Workbook.SaveAs($xlsx,51)
$excel.Quit()
```

Edit

```
Import-Csv path/to/myfile.csv -Delimiter ";" | Export-Csv path/to/outputfile.csv
```

This did not work for me, nothing changed. I tried but in Excel they are still in one column.

Comment: Could you show us some scripts you tried?

Comment: You already have 3 columns (they're separated by semicolons). Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're facing. Are you having issues importing this into Excel?

Comment: Try [`$query.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = $true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/querytable-textfilesemicolondelimiter-property-excel) instead of `$query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $delimiter`. [See also](http://www.rjsherman.com/vba/2014/import-txt-or-csv-file-into-excel-via-a-macro-querytable/).

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for [Import-Csv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) and [Export-Csv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)

```
Import-Csv path/to/myfile.csv -Delimiter ";" | Export-Csv path/to/outputfile.csv
```

As per [ConnerLSW's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44819997/separate-one-column-to-three-via-ps/44820068#comment76621253_44820068), the `-Header` parameter is useful to specify headers. Otherwise PowerShell will automatically use the 1st row as headers.

**Edit**
Your data is already in 3 columns, delimited by `;`. The code changes this to `,`, which creates a standard file of **C**omma **S**eperated **V**alues. Excel might not recognise this when you open the file, depending on settings.

Programmatically, you could use [`Workbooks.OpenText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel) on your original file, setting the `Semicolon` argument to `$true`.

In the GUI, you can turn a single column into multiple columns using Text-To-Columns:

[[image: Text to Columns[1]]

Comment: he doesn't have any headers in the file, might want to make a note about `-Header`

Comment: @ConnorLSW Thanks, added.

Comment: I see Text to Columns it's key to do it. Tried manually and working, but don't know how to put this in PS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the import/export fails if the file name is correct

```
PS> Get-Content .\test.csv
data1;data2;data3

data1;data2;data3

data1;data2;data3

PS> import-csv .\test.csv -delimiter ';'

data1 data2 data3
----- ----- -----
data1 data2 data3
data1 data2 data3

PS> import-csv .\test.csv -delimiter ';' -header Col1,Col2,Col3

Col1  Col2  Col3
----  ----  ----
data1 data2 data3
data1 data2 data3
data1 data2 data3

PS> import-csv .\test.csv -delimiter ';' -header Col1,Col2,Col3|export-csv .\test2.csv -notype
PS> gc .\test2.csv
"Col1","Col2","Col3"
"data1","data2","data3"
"data1","data2","data3"
"data1","data2","data3"
```

If you want to get rid of the -Header

```
PS> Get-Content test2.csv| select -skip 1 |Set-content .\test3.csv
> Get-Content .\test3.csv
"data1","data2","data3"
"data1","data2","data3"
"data1","data2","data3"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Header = "Header1,Header2,Header3"
$Source = "C:\TEMP\Loginy_Nieaktywne_temp.csv"
$OutFile = "C:\TEMP\Outfile.csv

$header | Out-file $OutFile

Get-content -Path $Source | Foreach {$_.Replace(";",",") | 
  Out-File $OutFile -Append}
```

This will create a new file with the headers listed in the first line.
We can the get the existing data using the get content command and replace the semi-colons with commas, add them to the new file and we have a properly constructed CSV file.

Comment: A code only answer is not high quality.   Please edit your question to explain what your code does and how it solves the problem.